# how to get the form value from mailer in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, smtp, sendmail

i am sending a mail via SMTP contains form and when form is submit then i want to get the form details and show to form submitted action URL

This is the form

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="thanks.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name1 " id="name1" />

<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

action URL where(thanks.php) i am trying to get the form value

```
<?php echo $_POST['name1']; ?>
```

but nothing shows, what wrongs with my code?

Comment: try with `name="name1"` instead of `name="name1 "` because you have an extra space in you input field.

Comment: i tried this but still now showing the submitted form value.

Comment: then just use `print_r($_POST);` in your thanks.php which provide you all the submitted data

Comment: @jogesh_p i used it and it shows `Array ( )`

Comment: @JassiOberoi are you trying to access the content from an email form??

Comment: @JassiOberoi give the full path in form, because you are trying to access the data from outside of your server that's why you have to give full path on your action tag, and this is only the solution

Comment: @jogesh_p - actually i trying it with the full URL, and for some reason i can not show here.

Comment: @jogesh_p - you know, that's why it shows the thanks.php page

Answer (score 1):

provide the complete url of your php file. becoz it post from a remote server.

action="http://www.yoursite.com/thanks.php"

More Details : [TechNew.In](http://www.technew.in)

Comment: yes i am providing the complete URL but i can't mentioned on it, this is not the right solution.

Comment: @Dino Babu Why the full path on action tag??

Comment: becoz. Jassi Oberoi told that he is sending the form as email content.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. It maybe have something to do with your installation or testing environment.

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Try that in your thanks.php to make sure that your server is getting the posted content. You could also try some dummy content outside the PHP tags to ensure that your form is posting to the correct file, again inside your thanks.php

```
<em>Dummy content</em>
<?php echo 'PHP test'; ?>
```

As a final resort, test your request

```
<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>
```

If none of these result in your form content, you probably have an error in your server installation or client.

Check the post request from your browser using tools like Firebug. Check you PHP by writing simpler scripts, that simply check for the presence of the $_REQUEST and $_POST variables.

Comment: for testing dummy text, i used `echo $_POST['name1']."testing";`
it shows only `testing` not the form value

Comment: @JassiOberoi then try with `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Try accessing the $_REQUEST variable instead, `echo $_REQUEST['name1'];`

Comment: You might be having some installation troubles with PHP and your web server. As a last resort, why not test your scripts with a GET method?

Comment: The best you can do here is finish writing your SMTP mailer and then deal with the fact that your environment is somehow broken. Could be the browser, the web server, or even PHP.

Comment: @NickCaballero - i can not test with get method because i m getting 5 email id from user and save it to my database

Comment: @NickCaballero - if might be problem in SMTP then it can not send the mail, see my SMTP functionality is working just fine, the only problem with getting the form value.